# Paged search returning incorrect amount of results

Tags: java, ldap

Tried implementing the page results control to my code to get past the 1000 users limit but it only returns as many users as I've set the page size to (e.g. page size is set to 20, it will only return 20 users). If I set the page size to over 1000, it will still max out at 1000.

Here's my current code:

```
public void setupStupidConnection()
{   
String ldapURL = "ldap://myldapurl";
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
//set security credentials, note using simple cleartext authentication
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,"simple");
env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout", "10000");

env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"username");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,"password");

//connect to my domain controller
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,ldapURL);
}

public void stupidSearch(String searchOptions)
{
String tempString = "";

try
{
    LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env,null);
      // Activate paged results
    int pageSize = 20;
    byte[] cookie = null;
    ctx.setRequestControls(new Control[] { new PagedResultsControl(pageSize,
        Control.NONCRITICAL) });
    int total;

    //Specify the attributes to return
    String returnedAtts[]={"Name", "samAccountName", "mail", "UserAccountControl", "distinguishedName"};
    searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);

    //Specify the search scope
    searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

    //specify the LDAP search filter
    String searchFilter;
    if(!"".equals(search))
    {
        switch(searchOptions)
        {
            case "Starts with...":
               searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user) (objectCategory=person) (CN=" + search + "*))";    
            break;
            case "Ends with...":
               searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user) (objectCategory=person) (CN=*" + search + "))";
            break;
            case "Contains...":
               searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user) (objectCategory=person) (CN=*" + search + "*))";
            break;
            case "Equals...":
               searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user) (objectCategory=person) (CN=" + search + "))";
            break;
            default:
               searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user) (objectCategory=person) (CN=" + search + "*))"; 
            break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user) (objectCategory=person))";
    }

    //Specify the Base for the search
    String searchBase;
    switch(searchPath)
    {
        case "A":
            searchBase = "OU=Accounts1";
        break;
        case "B":
            searchBase = "OU=Accounts2";
        break;
        case "C":
            searchBase = "OU=Accounts3";
        break;
        case "D":
            searchBase = "OU=Accounts4";
        break;
        default:
            searchBase = "OU=Accounts1";
        break;
    }
do
{
    System.out.println(searchBase);
    // Search for objects using the filter
        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ctx.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls);

        //Loop through the search results
        while (answer.hasMoreElements())
        {
            SearchResult sr = (SearchResult)answer.next();
            Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();

            tempString = attrs.get("distinguishedName").toString();
            tempString = tempString.substring(tempString.indexOf(",")+4);
            tempString = tempString.substring(0, tempString.indexOf(",DC="));
            String[] reverseString = tempString.split(",OU=");
            List<String> reverseList = Arrays.asList(reverseString);  
            Collections.reverse(reverseList);
            tempString = "";

            for (String reverseString1: reverseString)
            {
                tempString = tempString + "\\" + reverseString1;
            }
            tempString = tempString.substring(1);
            location.add(tempString);

            String enableCheck = attrs.get("UserAccountControl").toString().replaceAll(".*: ", "");
            String isEnabled = isActive(enableCheck).toString();
            results1.add(attrs.get("Name").toString());
           // System.out.println(attrs.get("Name").toString());
            results2.add(attrs.get("samAccountName").toString());
            results4.add(isEnabled);

            if (attrs.get("mail") != null)
            {
                results3.add(attrs.get("mail").toString());
            }
            else
            {
                results3.add("");
            }

            Control[] controls = ctx.getResponseControls();

            if (controls != null) 
            {
              for (int i = 0; i < controls.length; i++) 
              {
                if (controls[i] instanceof PagedResultsResponseControl) 
                {
                  PagedResultsResponseControl prrc = (PagedResultsResponseControl) controls[i];
                  total = prrc.getResultSize();
                  if (total != 0) 
                  {
                    System.out.println("***************** END-OF-PAGE "
                        + "(total : " + total + ") *****************\n");
                  } 
                  else 
                  {
                    System.out.println("***************** END-OF-PAGE "
                        + "(total: unknown) ***************\n");
                  }
                  cookie = prrc.getCookie();
                }
              }
            } 
            else 
            {
              System.out.println("No controls were sent from the server");
            }
            // Re-activate paged results
            ctx.setRequestControls(new Control[] { new PagedResultsControl(
                pageSize, cookie, Control.CRITICAL) });
        } 
    } while (cookie != null);
    ctx.close();
}

catch (NamingException e)
{
    System.out.println("Search error: " + e);
    System.exit(-1);
} catch (IOException ex) 
{
    Logger.getLogger(ADData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
 Logger.getLogger(ADData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

I've changed a few things to hide some company data. For every user it returns, it always outputs "No controls were sent from the server".

Any idea of what could be causing it?

Answer (score 2):

You've used `Control.NONCRITICAL`. From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/naming/ldap/PagedResultsControl.html#PagedResultsControl-int-boolean-):

> `criticality` - If true then the server must honor the control and return search results as indicated by pageSize or refuse to perform the search. If false, then the server need not honor the control.

So you're basically saying you're okay with it not honouring your page size. If you really, really need the page size to be honoured, used `Control.CRITICAL` - but be aware that that may cause the request to fail entirely.

If you don't mind only receiving 1000 results *at a time* you need to use the pagination appropriately, setting the server-generated cookie to retrieve subsequent pages. It looks like you're trying to do that via the second `ctx.setRequestControls` call, but your code is somewhat broken:

- Your `while (cookie != null)` loop isn't at the end of a `do` block, so I believe you've actually got code equivalent to:

  while (answer.hasMoreElements())
     {
         ...
     }
     while (cookie != null)
     {
         ctx.close();
     }
- You're not performing the search again. I wouldn't personally expect setting the controls to automatically perform a new search. (I haven't used the LDAP API for ages, but I'd expect you to need to call `ctx.search` for it to have an effect.)

Comment: Hi, I've tried this but I still get the same result, unfortunately.

Comment: @acidrain: Tried what, exactly, with what exact result? You've described various situations and I've suggested various solutions.

Comment: @acidrain: I've noticed some more problems in the code. (It would have been helpful if you'd shortened it - there's a lot of irrelevant code in there.)

Comment: Sorry, you had edited your response after I had left my comment. 
At that point, I had tried changing it to "Control.CRITICAL". 

And yes, you're right, I made a bit of a big mistake by leaving the "do" out there. I've fixed that now but I still appear to only getting 20 users for a page file size of 20 or 500 users for a page file size of 500.

The example I used was from here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/newstuff/examples/PagedSearch.java

Comment: @acidrain: So have you added logging to see whether you're getting a response cookie at all? I would concentrate on that side of things - use a page size of 20, and work on making sure you perform the expected number of searches.